# Compare dictionary in template django

Tags: python, jquery, django

**views.py :**

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
def TaskCreateView(request,pk,todo_id):
  completed={}
  if not request.user.is_authenticated:
      return redirect('accounts:index')
  elif User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk,mentor__isnull=True).exists():
      instance = get_object_or_404(Level, pk=pk)
      messages.warning(request, 'You have not added a trainer yet')
      print("TRAINER ILADA")
      return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
  else:
      instance = get_object_or_404(Level, pk=pk)
      qs = instance.todo_set.get(id=todo_id)
      #user = Task.objects.filter(student=request.user)
      todo = Task.objects.filter(todo=qs, student=request.user)
      if todo.exists():
            messages.warning(request,"ALready completed")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
  form  = StudentTaskForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
          if form.is_valid():
              form.instance.user = 
  User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
              obj = form.save(commit=False)
              obj.student = request.user
              obj.todo = qs
              obj.level = instance
              obj.save()
      ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Images,form=ImageForm,min_num=0,max_num=3,validate_min=True,extra=3)
      if request.method == 'POST':
          formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
          queryset=Images.objects.none())
          if formset.is_valid():
              for form in formset.cleaned_data:
              try:
                  image = form['image']
                  Images.objects.create(post=todo[0],image=image)
              except KeyError:
                  pass
              return redirect('student:dashboard')
      else:
          formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Images.objects.none())
          notifications = Notification.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)

      context={
        'form': form,
        "qs": qs,
        'formset': formset,
        'notifications': notifications,
        'completed':completed,
        'hubnotify': hubnotifications,
        'acceptnotify': acceptnotify,
        'follownotify': follownotify,
      }
      return render(request,'task_form.html',context)
```

**inside tempate:**

```
{% for key,value in completed.items }
    {% if {{value}} == True %}
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $('[data-click="swal-taskcompleted"]').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(), swal({
                    title: "Already Completed",
                    text: "You have already completed this task!",
                    icon: "error",
                    buttons: {
                        cancel: {
                            text: "Cancel",
                            value: null,
                            visible: !0,
                            className: "btn btn-default",
                            closeModal: !0
                        },
                    }
                })
            });
        </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for obj in task.todo_set.all %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button style="width: 100%;" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ obj.id }}" aria-expanded="true">
                    <span class="mytaskbutton"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span></i> &nbsp; {{ obj.name }}
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="{{ obj.id }}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                {{ obj.description }}
                <div>
                  <a data-click="swal-taskcompleted" href="{% url 'student:task-form' task.id obj.id %}" style="width: 100%;" type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">Proceed</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want show a popup message if an todo object already exists. What do I pass to the template to load script based on this condition?

`if todo.exists()`: I want to show the popup instead of messages using django messages  ,else go the task_form which enables user to submit the form. `todo` is a task object. Task  objects gets
saved only if the form is valid.

Comment: Place code properly so that anyone can get the issue and help you instently.

Comment: ok done @AnoopKumar

Comment: I have shared the link under answer  please go through it. You will find your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer [this link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/09/06/django-tip-14-messages-framework.html) for flash message setup in django.

**Note:** You have to pass success, warning and info according to the your requiremnent

Comment: I understand. But can this message be displayed as a popup ,like using jquery?with animation

Comment: I use it and its working but when i do sweetify in todo.exists(): ... If it doesnt exist then its loading form and when i press back button ,its showing popup again!.

Comment: probably a bug? :/